# REST call using node and express succeeds locally but fails once deployed to azure

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, express

I have a pretty basic REST call that is written using node / express that takes 2 datetimes as parameters(http://localhost:3000/schedules/'2012-06-28T16:00:00'/'2012-06-28T19:00:00')  It works fine locally when I run my tests against the node executable directly(on windows and on my mac) but when I deploy it to Azure via git, I get the infamous yellow screen.

The debugging log from azure is empty(never getting to my console.logs in node) so I'm guessing that the error is occurring somewhere in iisnode before it gets routed to the node exe.  The call does work fine if I use the following format (http://localhost:3000/schedules/2012-06-28/2012-06-29).  I was about to install iisnode to test a little more but I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue before I delve an deeper.

Here's some partial chunks of code:

routes

```
app.param('startdate',
function(req, res, next, startdate) {
    req.startdate = startdate;
    next();
});

app.param('enddate',
function(req, res, next, enddate) {
    req.enddate = enddate;
    next();
});

app.get('/schedules/:startdate/:enddate',scheduleController.getSchedulesByStartDateAndEndDate);
```

scheduleController

```
exports.getSchedulesByStartDateAndEndDate = function(req, res){
    console.log('getSchedulesByStartDateAndEndDate');
    console.log('StartDate'+req.params.startdate);
    console.log('EndDate'+req.params.enddate);
    ScheduleProvider.getSchedulesByStartDateAndEndDate(req.params.startdate,     req.params.enddate,function(schedules){
        res.send(schedules);
    });
};
```

scheduleProvider

```
ScheduleProvider.prototype.getSchedulesByStartDateAndEndDate =     function(startdate,enddate,callback){
console.log(startdate);
console.log(enddate);
var stDate = startdate;
var endDate = enddate;
if (stDate !== undefined) {
    var startDate = new Date(unescape(stDate.toString()).replace(/'/gi, ""));
    endDate = new Date(endDate === undefined ? startDate: unescape(endDate.toString()).replace(/'/gi, ""));
    var sttimes = getTimes(startDate);
    var endtimes = getTimes(endDate);
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
    console.log(sttimes[0]);
    console.log(sttimes[1]);
    console.log(endtimes[0]);
    console.log(endtimes[1]);

    Schedule.find({
        $or: [
        {
            'StartDate': {
                $gte: sttimes[0],
                $lt: endtimes[1]
            }
        },
        {
            'EndDate': {
                $gt: sttimes[0],
                $lte: endtimes[1]
            }
        }
        ]
    }, function(err, schedules){
    callback(schedules);
}).sort('StartDate', 'ascending');
}
};
```

I'm using mongoose to make the calls but I don't think it's ever getting to the provider or controller code.  It's almost like azure is not liking the dates passed in and throwing an exception.

Comment: Is it Windows Azure Web Role or Websites?

Comment: This is using the websites stuff release 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Why you are using port 3000? You can still use default port 80 with URL as htp://yourwebsitename.azurewebsites.net/schedules/2012-06-28/2012-06-29. Do you have to use port 3000 fixed in your node code? Can u also try if just basic node.js code works?

Comment: That's just for running it locally against the node executable(set to development node_env).  On the azure site it's using port 80(set to production node_env).  I have other REST services that I can access fine in the same azure site.  It's just the one where I'm passing 2 date times that I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: Oh, in that case it seems something code specific on Azure. if you past your code, i might take a look at suggest something.

Comment: I pasted in the most of the route code.  I can provider more if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running locally, you are using Node directly to host the application. When running in Windows Azure Web Sites you are using both IIS and IISNode as well as Node. I suspect you are having trouble with IIS handling the single quotes and Node (locally) not doing so. You should try running the site locally in IIS (with IISNode) to see if there is the same problem. Possibly the easiest way to do that is to run the site in the Windows Azure Emulator since you can then use the tooling to deploy your application.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been trying for the past day or so to get iisnode working but no luck so far.  I've had some other weirdnesses with azure that I have to look into as well so I'll try messing around with the quotes.  Thanks for your help.